# Vuetify v-calendar: Show Event Name by Selected Days

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

An example of an event would be:

```
const event = {
   name: 'Sample Event',
   starting_date: '2020-10-01',
   ending_date: '2020-10-31',
   selected_days: [1, 3, 5], // 1 = Monday ... 7 = Sunday
}
```

By default, the `event`'s name appears at the start of the week:
[v-calendar with event names at the start of each week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFBln.png)

How do I make the `event`'s name appear according to its `event.selected_days` *(Monday, Wednesday, Friday)* as shown here: [v-calendar - event names on selected days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4mcH.jpg)

Comment: Please post the relevant Vue/Vuetify code that demonstrates what you've tried

Comment: @Zim I'm rather lost and couldn't figure out where to begin, but here's the code for the component: https://pastebin.com/SaBkWH6P I can't seem to find in the docs how override the way the calendar names the events